# is clojurescript suited for use with Sencha/ExtJS?

Tags: clojurescript

there is a trivial sample gist of using clojurescript with Sencha. I thought clojurescript was designed with first-class interop with javascript libraries in mind, but the more I read the more it seems that only Google Closure is a first class citizen to clojurescript, and interop with other javascript frameworks isn't important to them.

i see no reason why it can't work, am i missing something? i don't want to be 2 or 3 weeks into a prototype before giving up due to problems i can't forsee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any external JavaScript library. The main issue - if the library doesn't provide an externs.js, then you'll have trouble compiling your ClojureScript with the external library under advanced compilation. That may or may not matter for your use case.